# Can Outlook be configured to only quote a selected portion of an email when replying?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

After reading an email I would like to select the text to which I intend to respond, hit reply, and have the rest of the text deleted such that only the text I selected is contained in the reply-to email.

I cannot figure out how to have Outlook 2010 do this for me. When I reply, it includes all the text of the email to which I am replying.

I would like to automate the deletion of everything except the selected portion of the original email.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that this is possible at the moment.

Comment: I was just about to ask the same thing. Me neither knows of a way. Will report back if I find anything. This is so annoying, most clients have this feature and I just assumed Outlook does as well. I am forced to use Outlook 2007 at my new job. Thunderbird fixed this perfectly at my old job!

Answer (score 3):

Outlook 2010 doesn't offer this feature, but you could probably simulate it with a VBA script.

Oddly, Outlook 2011 (Mac) has the exact behavior you desire built-in, and a vocal contingent of Windows switchers want to disable it.

Comment: Any idea how to disable it?

Answer (score -2):

Just switch to Thunderbird: it's free software and has this feature too, among others. You can simply select the text you want to reply to and when hitting "reply" you'll have that text quoted, and only that.